# Access list of lists in a random way

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a list of lists and populate them as required, but I'm getting  array out of bounds exception. My code is:

```
List<List<String>> seperatedData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
int index;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] data = line.split(",");
    index = data[0].hashCode() % redCount;

    if(seperatedData.get(index) == null) {
            List<String> single = new ArrayList<String>();
            seperatedData.add(single);
            seperatedData.get(index).add(line);
    } else {
            seperatedData.get(index).add(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `seperatedData` is an empty `List`. So the first time `if(seperatedData.get(index) == null)` is executed you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not matter the value of `index`.

Comment: If I catch that exception and create a new List<String>, how do I fill it in exactly the right spot? Say my `index` is 3 for the first time, how do I make `seperatedData` contain `{null, null, null, data}`?

Comment: This is not how an `ArrayList` works. Do you know the exact number of different index ? If so, you could use a basic array of `List<String>` like `List<String> [] seperatedData  = new List<String> [number of possible index]`. If you really want to use `List<List<String>>` do a for loop that set "high enough" number of entries to null: `seperatedData .add(null)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot us a `List` this way:
Lets say you have list with `5` elements and try, to add something to index `10`. It is `null`, so you create new sub list and add it to collection. However it will not be added at tenth position, but it will be accessible at next index (in this case it will by 5, making 6 items total).

so code below is wrong

```
        seperatedData.add(single);
        seperatedData.get(index).add(line);
```

to fix it use Map

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> seperatedData = new HashMap<>();
```

and use it:

```
if(seperatedData.get(index) == null) {
            List<String> single = new ArrayList<String>();
            seperatedData.put(single);
            seperatedData.get(index).add(line);
    } else {
            seperatedData.get(index).add(line);
    }
```

now it should work fine;